# Angular ReferenceError : Calling typescript function from html form or button

Tags: javascript, html, angular

So I'm pretty new to using Angular and I have a new Angular component, one TS file and one HTML file. In the HTML File, I have a form that is supposed to call a function in the corresponding typescript file when the submit button is pressed. Seems simple, but I'm constantly getting the following error :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: validateLogin is not defined
>       at :4200/HTMLInputElement.onclick (http:/localhost:4200/validateLogin();?email=email%40lol.com&password=password:13:283)
>   onclick @ validateLogin();?email=email%40lol.com&password=password:13
>   VM569:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: validateLogin is not defined
>       at :1:1

Two ReferenceErrors, one for the attempt with onclick and once for the attempt with the action attribute in form. On submit, I want the div to disappear, and the text "Success" to display. Here is the two files :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NullAstVisitor } from '@angular/compiler';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'TaManagementApp';
  toggleLoginHTML = true;

  constructor() {
    this.toggleLoginHTML = true;
  } 

  validateLogin() {
//  if ()
    this.toggleLoginHTML = false;
  }
}
```

And

```
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<div *ngIf=toggleLoginHTML>
  <div style="text-align:center">
    <h1>
      TA Management System
    </h1>
  </div>
  <button onclick='validateLogin()'></button>
  <div style="text-align:center">
    <form action="javascript:validateLogin()">
      Email: <input type="email" name="email" value="email"><br>
      Password: <input type="password" name="password" value="password"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick='validateLogin()'>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<div *ngIf=!toggleLoginHTML>
  <h1>
    Success
  </h1>
</div>
```

Any insight for a beginner would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You should use the built in click bindings `(click)="validateLogin()"`

Answer (score 1):

Like user184994 and qiAlex said, you should use Angular built in click binding by using `(click)="validateLogin()"` instead of `onclick`.

However I wanted to suggest you to try an take a look at the [Angular Reactive Form Guide](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) in which they explain fairly well how to implement a straightforward binding between your form and your model and possibly build very complex forms. 
Also take a look at the [Form Validation Guide](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation) for some deeper information on how to validate your form inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
<button onclick='validateLogin()'></button>
...
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick='validateLogin()'>
```

Try

```
<button (click)="validateLogin()"></button>
...
<input type="submit" value="Submit" (click)="validateLogin()">
```